# funcion buscar por string

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de implementar un un metodo que me cuente la cantidad de zonas que hay en el vector estoy utilizando el metodo `strcmp` pero me sale un error estoy utilizando la libreria `#include <string.h>` es la primera vez que lo uso y no se que hacer aqui les dejo mi codigo

```
void ContarPorZona(string zona){
    int cont=0,cont2=0;
     for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
    if(strcmp (zona,"residencial") == 0){
        cont++;
    }
    if(strcmp (zona,"parque") == 0){
        cont2++;
    }
    }
    cout<<"la cantidad de clientes residenciales son: "<<cont<<endl;
    cout<<"la cantidad de clientes del parque son: "<<cont2<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería bueno que pongas tu código dentro de las etiquetas `{ }` y ofrezcas un poco mas de detalle sobre tu problema, al igual que un poco mas de tu código para ver mejor tu situación.

La función `strcmp` sirve para comparar una cadena con otra cadena. Esta devuelve el valor 0 si son iguales, pero, en tu caso quieres contar las veces que se repite una cadena.

Ejemplo:

```
if(!strcmp(str1, str2))
{
 cout<<"Son iguales";
 vecesRepetidas++; // Variable contadora tipo INT
}
```

Otra forma es con:

```
if (strcmp(str1,str2) == 0)
```

Otra forma es con `string::compare`, devuelve 0 si son iguales:

```
std::string str1 ("manzana");
std::string str2 ("coco");

  if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
    vecesRepetidas++; // Variable contadora tipo INT
```

Incluyendo una variable contadora puedes saber cuántas veces se ha repetido una cadena.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: compa muchas gracias ahora me aparece este error [Error] 'strcmp' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Puedes editar tu post inicial y pegar tu código correctamente?, es dificil ayudarte sin ver tu código.

Comment: Agregaste `#include <string.h>` al inicio?.

Comment: si lo voy a ver si descargo la libreria y la agrego  compa y como se utilizaria este que me dijo arriba std::string

Comment: @RigobertoOviedoBolaños He editado mi respuesta con un ejemplo. Espero que te sirva uno de los ejemplos, no olvides agregar la librería. Prueba y si te sirvió, no olvides seleccionar la Respuesta como Aceptada.

Comment: strcmp se usa para comparar cadenas, es decir, tipo Char, pero lo que estás comparando son strings. Lo digo porque yo también hacía eso al principio y me daba error. Mira a ver, quizá ese sea el problema.